# Centos 7.5 autofs posix acl support

Tags: centos, automounting, acl, autofs

On centos 7.5 I have mounted NFS share(from isilon server) via autofs service.
Now when I run

```
setfacl -d -m g::rwx /path/to/share/location
```

it gives error

```
setfacl: /path/to/share/location Operation not supported
```

Does the autofs support the posix ACL or not? Note: on local path same command works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an NFS mount from an NFSv4 server that supports ACLs, you will need to use the [nfs4_setfacl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nfs4_setfacl) command to set acls.  The syntax isn’t quite the same.

Comment: Here i have NFSv3

Comment: There isn’t a standard for posix ACLs on nfsv3, and I believe it depends on the implementation, requiring a separate RPC daemon.